# Setting Variables within Makefile commands

Tags: linux, variables, makefile, gnu-make

I'm facing a silly problem with GNU makefile.
I want to define two targets to build a c program; one with debugging and the other without.

```
runNoDebug: setNoDeb objs runMe

runDebug: setDeb objs runMe

setNoDeb:
     {EXPORT} MyDEBUG= -O3

setDeb:
     {EXPORT} MyDEBUG="-DDEBUG=1 -g"

objs: cFiles
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(cFiles) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(MYDEBUG)

runme: objs
    ./oo
```

Errors arise on running this makefile, the command to set debugging executes on the subshell causing errors. If "Export" is added, the variable is defined in that subshell.

I want to define this variable in the makefile iteself to be used while building objects.

Is it possible? Or should I duplicate the "objs: cFiles" target?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I configure my makefile for debug and release builds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079832/how-can-i-configure-my-makefile-for-debug-and-release-builds)

Answer (score 2):

You need [target-specific variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) :

> This feature allows you to define different values for the same variable, based on the target that make is currently building.

```
runNoDebug: setNoDeb runMe

runDebug:   setDeb runMe

setNoDeb:   CFLAGS += -O3
setNoDeb:   objs

setDeb: CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG=1
setDeb: CFLAGS += -g
setDeb: objs

objs: $(cFiles)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@
```