# How to add release target to Makefile?

Tags: makefile, release, gnu-make

I have following Makefile, and I would like to configure it to produce debug build by default and release build by specifying corresponding target.

The problem I am trying to solve right now is following, - project contains unit tests, and I want them to be included in default build, but excluded from release, so I am added release target to Makefile:

```
FC      = ifort
FFLAGS  = -c -free -module modules -g3 -warn all -warn nounused
LDFLAGS = -save-temps -dynamiclib

INTERFACES = src/Foundation.f units/UFoundation.f units/Asserts.f units/Report.f
EXCLUDES   = $(patsubst %, ! -path './%', $(INTERFACES))
SOURCES    = $(INTERFACES) \
             $(shell find . -name '*.f' $(EXCLUDES) | sed 's/^\.\///' | sort)
OBJECTS    = $(patsubst %.f, out/%.o, $(SOURCES))
EXECUTABLE = UFoundation

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

release: SOURCES := $(filter-out units/%.f, $(SOURCES))
release: OBJECTS := $(filter-out units/%.o, $(OBJECTS))
release: EXECUTABLE := 'Foundation.dlyb'
release: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo 'Linking to $@...'
    @$(FC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o out/$@

out/%.o: %.f
    @echo 'Compiling $@...'
    @mkdir -p modules
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @$(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning..."
    @rm -rf modules out $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Unfortunate, it doesn't help - result of 'make' and 'make release' are the same (make release compiles unit test files as in default). I already looked to similar questions, like [How can I configure my makefile for debug and release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079832/how-can-i-configure-my-makefile-for-debug-and-release-builds), but without any success to solve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debug and release targets get build with different macros (e.g. `NDEBUG`) and different optimization levels. You normally do not want to mix debug and release object files, hence they need to be compiled into different directories.

I often use a different top-level build directory for different build modes this way:

```
BUILD := debug
BUILD_DIR := build/${BUILD}
```

And compiler flags this way:

```
cppflags.debug :=
cppflags.release := -DNDEBUG
cppflags := ${cppflags.${BUILD}} ${CPPFLAGS}

cxxflags.debug := -Og
cxxflags.release := -O3 -march=native
cxxflags := -g -pthread ${cxxflags.${BUILD}} ${CXXFLAGS}
```

And then build your objects into `BUILD_DIR`.

When you invoke it as `make BUILD=release` that overrides `BUILD := debug` assignment made in the makefile.