# Makefile set variable in target

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile where a variable `$DEBUG` decides whether to build for deployment or debugging. There is one main Makefile, and multiple platform-specific makefiles that get included. I want the variable `$DEBUG` to be set to `1` automatically when the target `test` is built.

The main makefile:

```
DEBUG := 0

test : override DEBUG := 1

DIST_DIR := dist/
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    BUILD_DIR := build/debug
else
    BUILD_DIR := build/deploy
endif


# detect operating system
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    UNAME := Windows
else
    UNAME := $(shell uname -s)
endif

# include platform-specific Makefile
export
ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    include Makefile.darwin
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    include Makefile.linux
endif
```

And the platform-specific `Makefile.linux`:

```
... 
CXX := clang++-3.8
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++14 -fPIC -I./external/include -fcolor-diagnostics
LDFLAGS := 
LDLIBS := -lpthread -lm


ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    CXXFLAGS += -g
else
    CXXFLAGS += -O3 -DNDEBUG
endif

... 

all : $(TARGET)


test : $(TEST_TARGET)
    $(TEST_TARGET)
```

So there are two rules for `test`: One in the main makefile sets the target-specific variable `$DEBUG`, and the one in `Makefile.linux` builds the test. The variables used for building (`$CXXFLAGS`, `$BUILDDIR`, and others) are set before the rules, and use conditionals.

Everything in the makefiles is working correctly, however calling `make test` does not alter the variable `$DEBUG`: both `$CXXFLAGS` and `$BUILDDIR` still get set to the values they would have for a deployment built.

Is there a way to first set `$DEBUG := 1` in `Makefile` when the target is `test`, and then normally proceed?
Or is there a special variable that contains the target name, for example

```
ifeq ($(MAKEFILE_TARGET), test)
    ...
endif
```

Comment: You can handle conditionals in a more elegant way in make: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35893827/412080

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`test : override DEBUG := 1` doesn't work because it declares a [target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) that is only visible within that recipe.

There *does* exist a variable containing the target names that were specified at the command line: [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals).  Note that it doesn't include the default target if it wasn't explicitly specified at the command line.

Example makefile:

```
DEBUG := $(filter test,$(MAKECMDGOALS))

all:
    @echo all : $(MAKECMDGOALS) : $(DEBUG) : $(if $(DEBUG),1,0)

test:
    @echo test : $(MAKECMDGOALS) : $(DEBUG) : $(if $(DEBUG),1,0)
```

Usage:

```
$ make
all : : : 0
$ make all
all : all : : 0
$ make test
test : test : test : 1
$ make all test
all : all test : test : 1
test : all test : test : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is to have your `test` target recursively invoke `make` with `DEBUG=1`. That works with included makefiles as well. Example:

```
DEBUG := 0

test:
  make DEBUG=1

DIST_DIR := dist/
...
```