# Make refuses to expand my variables in the g++ compilation line

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is my simple Makefile. I am trying to set the C macro "GIT_COMMIT" in my Makefile and pass it to the C program.

```
all: control

control: control.cpp serial_port.cpp
    GIT_COMMIT=5
    g++ -g -DGIT_COMMIT=$(GIT_COMMIT) -Wall $^ -o control -lpthread
```

Unfortunately, when I run make, I see this and make is completely ignoring my GIT_COMMIT variable. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
GIT_COMMIT=5
g++ -g -DGIT_COMMIT= -Wall control.cpp serial_port.cpp -o control -lpthread
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile set variable in target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174028/makefile-set-variable-in-target)

Comment: Yes, but in a much more complicated and unclear example. My question is superior for this problem due to its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

placing the setting of GIT_COMMIT as an action inside the 'control' rule will, as you discovered, not work to produce a macro.  suggest:

```
all: control

GIT_COMMIT := 5

control: control.cpp serial_port.cpp
    g++ -g -DGIT_COMMIT=$(GIT_COMMIT) -Wall $^ -o control -lpthread
```

Comment: Thank you for restoring my sanity.  I had no idea that variables "didn't work" inside rules.

Comment: @define_makefile, they don't work *to produce a macro*.  But in your particular case, the line in question works fine (as a shell command) to produce a *shell* variable.  `make` runs each recipe line in a separate shell, however, so it's not useful for a line to do nothing but set a (shell) variable.

Comment: Okay, that explains why. I'm surprised there is no warning!

Comment: How can there be a warning?  It's perfectly acceptable to assign a shell variable in a shell script, which is what you're doing here.  In any event, make doesn't even know that that's what you're doing: make doesn't have a shell script interpreter built into it.  It just takes the commands in the recipe and runs a shell and gives it that text: only the shell knows whether it's valid syntax (and again, this is perfectly valid syntax).