# Make: Variable assignment

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am facing the issue while accessing a variable from other makefile which is included.

i have test.mak which has variable LIBS32 := $(TESTLIBS)/$(NEW_PLAT32) 
i have included test.mak in other makefile and trying to assign that variable in one of the target.

```
extlib32: EXTLIBS = $(LIBS32)
extlib64: EXTLIBS = $(LIBS64)
```

The expected value of EXTLIBS should be '/home/testlib/extlibs/Linux' . But here when i print EXTLIBS the value which i am seeing is '/home/testlib/extlibs/'

Note:- When i jut print LIBS i can see the content as expected. But when i assigned to EXTLIBS and try to use it.. I can see word 'Linux' is missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You set `EXTLIBS` as a [target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) for target `extlib32`. Such variables are non-global and their value is only available in the target recipe and target's prerequisites, rather than globally (this is why `$(info $(EXTLIBS))` doesn't print the expected value).

To print its value you need to print it from the recipe of target `extlib32`, e.g.:

```
extlib32:
    @echo "EXTLIBS=${EXTLIBS}"
```

If `extlib32` and `extlib64` are `.PHONY` targets to build something then your original target-specific assignments should propagate to the dependencies and be available in their recipes. You just cannot print its value from the global makefile scope.

---

To have one makefile build both in 32 and 64-bit mode (as well as release and debug) you need to structure it differently and invoke `make` separately for each build mode. Example:

```
# User can overrided capitalized variables. E.g.
# make BUILD=release MODE=32 LDLIBS=-lrt
BUILD := debug
MODE := 64

build_dir := ${BUILD}/${MODE}

ldlibs.32 := my-32-bit-libs
ldlibs.64 := my-64-bit-libs
ldlibs := ${ldlibs.${MODE}} ${LDLIBS}

all :
    @echo "build_dir=${build_dir}"
    @echo "ldlibs=${ldlibs}"
```

Usage examples:

```
$ make 
build_dir=debug/64
ldlibs=my-64-bit-libs

$ make BUILD=release MODE=32
build_dir=release/32
ldlibs=my-32-bit-libs
```

[Another example for debug/release compiler options.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893827/412080)

Comment: Hi Maxim, I just print with $(info .$(EXTLIBS)) to check the value....BTW want to use that variable in my targets.. How can i use it? Is the assignment which i did above is not correct ?

Comment: @santosh Then just do `EXTLIBS := $(LIBS)` (nothing else on the line).

Comment: Hi Maxim, LIBS value will change based on 32bit or 64 bit build. Sorry if my question was not clear... I am updating my question for clarity.

Comment: @santosh Updated for you.

Comment: Hi Maxim, Thank you for the update... In my case how can i fix this.. Basically the requirement is if we are running 32bit build then EXTLIBS value should assign to $(LIBS32), If we are running 64bit build then  EXTLIBS value should assign to $(LIBS64).. Thats why i had above seperate targets for 32bit & 64bit which is not working as expected. How can we make it global... Could you please help fixing this?

Comment: @santosh Updated the answer for you.