# How to save make argument in a variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I am working on a (GNU) Makefile and need to save arguments in a variable.
Like if I give the command `make projectX`, then I need to assign `projectX` to some variable.

I tried to assign `projectX` like this, assuming that argument 1 would be `projectX`.

```
PRODUCT := "$1"
```

But this does not work.

What is the best way to assign make arguments in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

From the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals):

> Make will set the special variable `MAKECMDGOALS` to the list of goals you specified on the command line. If no goals were given on the command line, this variable is empty. Note that this variable should be used only in special circumstances.

And note that usually you would/should/must use `$@` to refer to the target of a rule.

Comment: There is also `$(MAKEFLAGS)`, which contains all other arguments (i.e. flags rather than tagets).

Comment: Remember that `MAKECMDGOALS` is a list and may be empty (if no target is provided) or have multiple targets (like in `make clean projectX`). Therefore while the answer is correct, I would rather use approach with a variable instead to have less tricky scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign variables in `make` command line:

```
make PRODUCT=bla
```

Which is often used for [debug/release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893827/412080):

```
make # builds debug version
make MODE=release # builds release version
```