# Makefile get calling rule name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to create a makefile so when calling it the syntax will be `make release` or `make debug`.

In order to do so, I have composed the following makefile:

```
release debug: mode := $@
release debug: build

build:
    *** actual build commands using $(mode) ***
```

But in the making process, when reaching the `build` rule, `$(mode)` seems to be empty.

Is there a better/proper build debug and release binaries?

Comment: Another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893827/412080

Answer (score 0):

The '$@' automatic variable is only available when building a target. It does not have a value when a rule is evaluated. As a result '$@' is not set during the execution of the line:

```
release debug: mode := $@
```

Consider setting up rules for 'build' and 'release'

```
release debug:
        $(MAKE) build mode=$@

build:
```

Or the alternative (which I think is less intuitive, but more efficient):

```
release: mode=release
debug: mode=debug

build:
    ...
```