# Makefile for different variants of program

Tags: makefile

I have a program, set up for experimental purposes, that can be build in different variants, controlled by preprocessor switches. At the moment, my makefile is setup such that it generates the binaries `build/[flags]`, where `flags` is a letter-encoding of the different variants to be build.

```
build/[flags]:
    linker commands

build/[flags]_objects/[filename].o: [filename].cpp
    compiler commands
```

I use secondary expansion to resolve all this, i.p., to decode the flag string and turn it into command line switches to the compiler. This is a bit hard to maintain, and I would like to know if there are better alternatives to that approach.

**Edit.** I admit that I wasn't very clear. Here is an example. My program is supposed to be compiled with and without `-DFLAG`. My binary will be called `d` (like default) for the version without and `f` for the version with the flag. My makefile goes roughly like this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

# Used for using $% in secondary expansion
PERCENT=%

# Decode the flag in the target name
decode_flag=$(if $(findstring f,$(1)),-DFLAG,)

# Build the executable
build/%.out: $$(patsubst $$(PERCENT).cpp,build/$$*/$$(PERCENT).o,$$(SRC))
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# Build the object files; the objects for binary build/x* in build/x/
build/%.o: $$(*F).cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(call decode_flag, $(*D)) -o $@ $<
```

I haven't specified `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `SRC`; they have the usual meaning.

I guess you'll admit that all this `patsubst`-stuff is hard to read. In reality, the `decode_flag` is slightly more complicated, but the principle stays the same.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your attempt with secondary expansion?  Also, include how you go about reading/decoding the flags.

Comment: A solution for a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893827/412080

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just do a for/eval loop.  Here's an example:

```
POSSIBLE_FLAGS := "d f"

CFLAGS_d = ""
CFLAGS_f = "-DFLAG"

SRC := ...

#
# flag_rules:
#   $1 - flag
#
define flag_rules

OBJS_$1 := $$(patsubst %.cpp,build_$1/%.o,$$(SRC))

# Build the executable
build_$1/%.out: $$(OBJS_$1)
    $$(CXX) $$(LDFLAGS) -o $$@ $$^

# Build the object files 
build_$1/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $$(@D)
    $$(CXX) -c $$(CXXFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS_$1) -o $$@ $$<

endef

$(foreach flag,$(POSSIBLE_FLAGS), \
   $(eval $(call flag_rules,$(flag))))
```

(Disclaimer -- I didn't actually run this, so I might have missed something)

Be careful to not put spaces around the `$(flag)` inside of the `$(call ...)` statement.   I switched up your conventions slightly -- all outputs for a particular flag appear in a directory called `build_$(flag)`.  Outside of this, the names appear the same.   With this, you can do `make build_f/blah` to build with flag `f`, or `make build_d/blah` to build with flag `d`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would be a bit more specific for the sake of readability, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
SRC := src/main.cpp src/moduleA/moduleA.cpp src/moduleB/moduleB.cpp
OBJ := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

# Customized linking flags per target
build/f.out: LDFLAGS += -Wl,--build-id

# Generic rule for linking
build/%.out: $$(addprefix build/$$*/,$(OBJ))
        echo $(LINK.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^

# Section for d variant (dependency rule only)
$(addprefix build/d/,$(OBJ)): build/d/%.o: %.cpp

# Section for f variant (dependency rule and customizations)
$(addprefix build/f/,$(OBJ)): build/f/%.o: %.cpp
$(addprefix build/f/,$(OBJ)): CXXFLAGS += -DFLAG

# Generic rule for compilation
build/%.o:
        echo $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

This approach uses [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) to explicitly define which object file is supposed to be created from which source file, while keeping compilation recipe once only. It also uses [target-specific variable assignment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) to keep flags set only for specific objects without complicating compilation recipe.

The explicit dependency rules are added for the sake of readability; this of course might be evaluated with second expansion if one wants to sacrifice readability for brevity.

Output (in parallel to show there is no interference):

```
$ make -s -j2 build/f.out build/d.out
g++ -DFLAG -c -o build/f/src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -DFLAG -c -o build/f/src/moduleA/moduleA.o src/moduleA/moduleA.cpp
g++ -DFLAG -c -o build/f/src/moduleB/moduleB.o src/moduleB/moduleB.cpp
g++ -c -o build/d/src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -c -o build/d/src/moduleA/moduleA.o src/moduleA/moduleA.cpp
g++ -c -o build/d/src/moduleB/moduleB.o src/moduleB/moduleB.cpp
g++ -Wl,--build-id -o build/f.out build/f/src/main.o build/f/src/moduleA/moduleA.o build/f/src/moduleB/moduleB.o
g++ -o build/d.out build/d/src/main.o build/d/src/moduleA/moduleA.o build/d/src/moduleB/moduleB.o
```