# Make not setting correctly the location of the source code

Tags: makefile

Here is a little problem that I've encountered:

I have the following project layout:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── inc
│   └── include.hpp
├── out
│   ├── debug
│   └── release
└── src
    └── main.cpp
```

And the following Makefile (which was copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830354), and edited a little bit by me, to adequate to my project):

```
# Compiler flags
CXX     := g++
CXXFLAGS    := -Wall -Werror -Wextra


# Project files
SRC_DIR     := src
SRCS        := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
INC_DIR     := inc
INCLUDES    := -I $(INC_DIR)
OBJS        := $(SRCS:.cpp:=.o)
EXE     := <ProgramName>
BUILD_DIR   := out

# Debug build settings
DBGDIR      := $(BUILD_DIR)/debug
DBGEXE      := $(DBGDIR)/$(EXE)
DBGOBJS     := $(addprefix $(DBGDIR)/, $(OBJS))
DBGCXXFLAGS := -g -O0 -DDEBUG

# Release build settings
RELDIR      := $(BUILD_DIR)/release
RELEXE      := $(RELDIR)/$(EXE)
RELOBJS     := $(addprefix $(RELDIR)/, $(OBJS))
RELCXXFLAGS := -O3 -DNDEBUG

.PHONY: all clean debug prep release remake

# Default build
all: prep release

# Debug rules
debug: $(DBGEXE)

$(DBGEXE): $(DBGOBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DBGCXXFLAGS) -o $(DBGEXE) $^

$(DBGDIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @echo $@ 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(DBGCXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# Release rules
release: $(RELEXE)

$(RELEXE): $(RELOBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(RELCXXFLAGS) -o $(RELEXE) $^

$(RELDIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(RELCXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

# Other rules
prep:
    @mkdir -p $(DBGDIR) $(RELDIR)

remake: clean all

clean:
    @rm -rf $(RELEXE) $(RELOBJS) $(DBGEXE) $(DBGOBJS)
    @echo "Cleaned!"
```

Produces the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'out/release/src/main.cpp', needed by 'out/release/<ProgramName>'.  Stop.
```

Where is the issue? And when does make assume that the directory of the source files is in '/out/release'? I'm still a noob writing makefiles, I've always been a little bit lazy and used Visual Studio even when targeting linux.

Any help is vastly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of small errors.

```
OBJS        := $(SRCS:.cpp:=.o)
```

You have an extra colon. As written, you change all instances of `.cc:`, but there are none, so `OBJS` is `src/main.cpp`.

You probably meant this:

```
OBJS        := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

But this gives `src/main.o`. You probably did not intend to keep the path. You can correct that with another line:

```
OBJS := $(notdir $(OBJS))
```

Then here:

```
$(RELDIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp
    ...
```

You are missing a slash. The correct line is

```
$(RELDIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    ...
```

The rule as written searches for a file that doesn't exist.

You can detect such errors yourself -- and correct them as you develop the makefile -- with diagnostics like this:

```
$(info OBJS is $(OBJS))
$(info RELOBJS is $(RELOBJS))
```

Write a small makefile that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: You're a life saver! I will follow the advice. Thank you very much!!