# I want to write makefile for C++ project which is able to make release build as well as debug build

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, gnu-make

Can we write a makefile which is able to create debug/ release build . The user will give choice which one should be made.

Comment: Yes of course you can. Just have two targets, one for release and one for debug.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079832/how-can-i-configure-my-makefile-for-debug-and-release-builds) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure my makefile for debug and release builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079832/how-can-i-configure-my-makefile-for-debug-and-release-builds)

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/cppfw/prorab it provides creating as many configs as you want, building each of them in separate directory

Answer (score 0):

you can use as @kaylum said and use different cflags. every target will get it's own cflags

```
CFLAGS1 = -ansi -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -g

CFLAGS2 = -ansi -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -DNDEBUG -O3
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled about it and couldn't find the best answer.My solution creates executables in different directories without mixing them. Here is the [answer](https://github.com/Kanonyy/CPP_GNU_MAKE-Debug-Release)